# Sorting JTable programmatically

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to sort a JTable programmatically?

I have my JTable's sort working (with setRowSorter) so that when the user presses any of the columns, the table gets sorted.

I know, SWingX JXTable would probably work, but I'd rather not go through the hassle because everything else is pretty much working now and I don't know how well NetBeans' visual editor handles JXTable etc.

**EDIT:** *The selected answer is referring to my (now removed) statement that the answer from Sun's pages didn't work for me. That was just an environment issue caused by my ignorance.*

Comment: can you post some code that you have tried?

Comment: Check out: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/Sorter.html

Comment: I was able to pretty easily add JXTable to NetBeans 6.7, so don't rule that out as an option. Maybe make a small test project to play with it before trying in your main project.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableBasic extends JPanel
{
    public TableBasic()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"Date", "String", "Integer", "Boolean"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {new Date(), "A", Integer.valueOf(1), Boolean.TRUE },
            {new Date(), "B", Integer.valueOf(2), Boolean.FALSE},
            {new Date(), "C", Integer.valueOf(19), Boolean.TRUE },
            {new Date(), "D", Integer.valueOf(4), Boolean.FALSE}
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers and editors to be used based on Class

            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                switch (column)
                {
                    case 0: return Date.class;
                    case 2: return Integer.class;
                    case 3: return Boolean.class;
                }

                return super.getColumnClass(column);
            }
        };


        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        // DefaultRowSorter has the sort() method

        ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey> list = new ArrayList<>();
        DefaultRowSorter sorter = ((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter());
        sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);
        list.add( new RowSorter.SortKey(2, SortOrder.ASCENDING) );
        sorter.setSortKeys(list);
        sorter.sort();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Basic");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TableBasic());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

Next time post your [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when something doesn't work.

Comment: You are right, I had issues with my environment and was not using the latest classes from Java-side (I'm doing half Clojure/half Java-project).

Comment: Use `Collections.singletonList(new RowSorter.SortKey(2, SortOrder.ASCENDING))` if you're lazy creating lists.

Answer (score 8):

You also can trigger row sorting by calling `toggleSortOrder()` on the `RowSorter` of your `JTable`:

```
table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(columnIndex);
```

Note, however, that (quoting the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html#toggleSortOrder%28int%29)):

> Reverses the sort order of the specified column. Typically this will reverse the sort order from ascending to descending (or descending to ascending) if the specified column is already the primary sorted column.

Though it is quicker, calling `setSortKeys()` as shown by @camickr (+1 to him) is the correct way to go (but you need to instanciate a `List`).