# Java color the head of a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to color the header of a jtable and I have no idea what my fault is, I appreciate the help

I leave part of the code:

```
// style jtable

        jTable_registry.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 12));
        jTable_registry.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
        jTable_registry.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(32, 136, 203));
        jTable_registry.getTableHeader().setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        jTable_registry.setRowHeight(25);
```

I'm doing the test to try to get what I want and in that simple way I can't change the background color of the header, it is still the default color ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: That looks correct to me. Are you referencing the correct table? Are you sure that you don't have a broken look and feel set, or that other code is changing your table header later? Create a button in your code that changes the color dynamically, and if that button works then you know there is an issue with the order that your code is initialized.

Comment: Works fine for me. I took the working code from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539329/sorting-jtable-programmatically/1539602#1539602 and just added the `setBackground(...)` statement as a proof of concept. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Works for me too. Maybe add a [property change listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html) to the `JTableHeader` that listens for changes to the "background" property?

Comment: Do you have custom header renderers which ignore the parent’s background color or simply do not fill their background?

Comment: I found the problem with the Nimbus visual theme

Answer (score 0):

The code works and makes the change of background color to the table headers, the problem I found with the Nimbus visual theme which uses `Painter` to render the headers and make them noticeable with effects and such for which it will ignore the instruction in a certain way: `setBackground`, this does not happen with Metal, GTK or the one that comes with the operating system.

```
private void Theme() {
  try {
    if(UIManager.getLookAndFeel().toString().contains("Nimbus"))
      UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey",new Color(32,136,203));
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The above modifies pre-established values within this Look And Feel through: `put`using a form of Key - Value pairs.