# Disable JTable cell in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to disable edit on double click in each cell from Jtable in Java Netbeans. The JTable is connected to sqlite database and shows the database table record.

```
 private void DisplayTable() {
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:clientrec.sqlite");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM client";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        t1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel (rs));
        
        } 
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } finally{
        try{
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

I also created onmouseclick event for the jtable to display selection in Jtextfields, combobox, jcalendar

```
      private void t1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) t1.getModel();
        int number=t1.getSelectedRow();
        String tc=t1.getModel().getValueAt(number, 0).toString();
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:clientrec.sqlite");

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE ID="+tc+"";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
        String id=rs.getString("ID");        
        String fullname=rs.getString("FullName");
        String phone=rs.getString("Phone");
        String allergy=rs.getString("Allergy");
        String date=rs.getString("Date1");
        String budgetpayed=rs.getString("BudgetPayed");
        String totalbudget=rs.getString("TotalBudget");
        String budgetleft=rs.getString("BudgetLeft");
        String currency=rs.getString("Currency");
        String datea=rs.getString("Dateappointment");
        String description=rs.getString("Description");
        
        FullName.setText(fullname);
        Phone.setText(phone);
        Allergy.setText(allergy);
        ((JTextField)Date1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText(date);
        BudgetP.setText(budgetpayed);
        TBudget.setText(totalbudget);
        BudgetL.setText(budgetleft);
        Curr.setSelectedItem(currency);
        ((JTextField)Date2.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText(datea);
        Desc.setText(description);
        }

    }catch (Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Textbooks and tutorials follow this convention. Learn by example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `isCellEditable(...)` method of the `JTable`:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: I already have Jtable name T1 in design mode, should it be in my case the below and where I should write it ?

JTable t1= new JTable(...)
{
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        return false;
    }
};

Comment: Don't use design mode. Learn how to write code manually. Then you are learning how to use Swing instead of learning the JDK. If you ever switch to a different IDE you would need to learn how that IDE works. I don't use an IDE so I don't know how you customize a class in your IDE. Note you will also need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the table so the data can be displayed properly. That is so numbers can be formatted and right aligned. The JTable chooses the renderer based on this method.

Comment: I wrote the code you mentioned but editing still works on double click.

Comment: Then you didn't write the code correctly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539329/sorting-jtable-programmatically/1539602#1539602 for an example of overriding a method of a JTable. When you run the code you will be able to edit the cell. Change the code to override the  `isCellEditable(...)` method as demonstrated above and you won't be able to edit the cell. This is the answer to your question. I can't help with the IDE, that is a different question.