# Trouble with adding JScrollPane to JTable initialized by TableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have some troubles with adding `JScrollPane` to `JTable` in my application. There are two classes: `Controller` and `Main` form.

In `Main` form the table is initialized as private variable, and in Controller I'm getting it using getter. Now I have such code in `Controller` to create and update table using `TableModel`:

```
private void updateTables(String[][] distanceMatrixData, String[] columnNames) {
    TableModel distanceMatrixModel = new DefaultTableModel(distanceMatrixData, columnNames);
    mainForm.getDistanceMatrix().setModel(distanceMatrixModel);
}
```

I don't have idea how to implement `JScrollPane` to this code because I don't create the table object.

Comment: When you create the JTable you add the table to the JScrollPane and add the scroll pane to the frame. Then when you update the model of the table the scrollbars will appear when required. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539329/sorting-jtable-programmatically/1539602#1539602 for a simple example.

Comment: *"I don't create the table object"* Are you using a drag'n'drop GUI designer? That doesn't bode well. Most people here won't help you figure out problems with your IDE. It's better to learn how to write the code yourself. Then you have complete control over components involved.