# Jtable adding rows with strings and doubles

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

Hi there i'm studing Java and i have some questions. I'm trying to populate a Jtable and sorting it:
i'm creating a model of an existing Jtable and adding it some data:

```
    ArrayList<Cliente> lista = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    lista = FachadaLogica.cargarTablaClientes();
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    modelo.addColumn("Cédula");
    modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
    modelo.addColumn("Dirección");
    modelo.addColumn("Departamento");
    modelo.addColumn("Código Postal");
    modelo.addColumn("Monto Total");
    this.tabla.setModel(modelo);  
   tabla.setAutoCreateRowSorter(Boolean.TRUE);
    Object clientes[]=new Object[6];
    String ci;
    String departamento = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        clientes[0] = lista.get(i).getCedula();
        clientes[1] = lista.get(i).getNombre();
        clientes[2] = lista.get(i).getDireccion();
        departamento = FachadaLogica.obtenerDepartamento(lista.get(i).getDepartamento());
        clientes[3] = departamento;
        clientes[4] = lista.get(i).getCodigoPostal();
        ci = lista.get(i).getCedula();
        clientes[5] = FachadaLogica.obtenerMontoCliente(ci);
        modelo.addRow(clientes);
    }
```

Result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLI4o.png]

My problem is when i try to sort it by "monto total" translated to english it is the money that the client must to pay, the method "obtenerMontoCliente" returns a Double but it sorts like a String.

```
    public static Double obtenerMontoCliente(String ci){
    Double resultado= 0.0;

    TrabajoPersistencia pers = new TrabajoPersistencia();
    try {
        resultado=pers.montoTotalCliente(ci);
    } catch (TrabajoExcepcion ex) {
       
    }
```

i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of your `TableModel` so the appropriate Comparator can be used. This will also allow the table to use the appropriate renderer for the column. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539329/sorting-jtable-programmatically/1539602#1539602 for a basic example.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked with the example!!