# Suppose I have a table, made using Swing, and I put it in a frame. How to set the frame dimensions to be table dimensions?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

So here is the basic code that I have written.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] list_of = {
            {"Chirag", "21", "Blue"},
            {"Manish", "21", "Green"}
    };
    
    Object[] column_name = {"Name", "Age", "Fav Color"};
    
    JTable table = new JTable(list_of, column_name);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Query");
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(scrollpane);
    
}
```

So where the dimensions (200,200) is, which is arbitrary, I would like the frame to be the size of table, so that it can display tables of various sizes.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: Don't attempt to set sizes manually. Instead you `pack()` the frame after adding the table to the frame. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539329/sorting-jtable-programmatically/1539602#1539602. If show how to get the actual size of the table before you pack the frame.

Comment: Also, the scrollpane needs to be added to the frame BEFORE you pack() the frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(100, 100));` just like you did, but you also have to pack the frame with `frame.pack();`.