# jTable only shows cells when clicked on (with custom renderer)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I am new to Java, so please forgive my ignorance. I am trying to create a jTable that will disable a checkbox based on the value of another cell. When I run this code either nothing displays or the table's cells only display when clicked on. A nudge in the right direction would help a lot. Thank you.

```
public class Enrollment extends javax.swing.JDialog {
   //public static String empState = "";
   //public static String empEffDate = "";
    /**
     * Creates new form Enrollment
     */
 
    
    
    public Enrollment(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        
        DefaultTableModel model;
        //load table
        String empSSN = JContacts.getCurrentSSN();
        
        
        String sqlStmt = "Select * from enrollment.empprodchoices left join "
                + "enrollment.plannames on plannames.prodidcode = empprodchoices.prodidcode"
                + " where empSSN= '" + empSSN + "'";
        
        System.out.println(sqlStmt);
        ResultSet rs = DBConn.getRS(sqlStmt);
        model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
      initUI();
      
       
        
        
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String[] rowData = new String[9];
                rowData[0] = rs.getString("productname");
                rowData[1] = rs.getString("options");
                rowData[2] = rs.getString("coveragelevel");
                rowData[3] = rs.getString("aftertaxcost"); //money check value
                rowData[4] = rs.getString("CoverageDate");
                rowData[5] = rs.getString("DeductionDate");
                rowData[8] = rs.getString("prodidcode");
                
                model.addRow((Object[]) rowData);
                //jTable1.repaint();
              }
           //instance table model
//jTable1.revalidate();
//jTable1.repaint();
//jTable1.updateUI();
          
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Enrollment.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        // initUI();
         
    }
private void initUI() {
    
    // Assuming jTable1 has already been initialized and populated
        // Modify the table model to control editability
       DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        
        // Get column identifiers from existing model
        Vector<String> columnIdentifiers = new Vector<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            columnIdentifiers.add(model.getColumnName(i));
        }

        jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(model.getDataVector(), columnIdentifiers) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                if (column == 8) return false;
                return !(column == 7 && getValueAt(row, 8).equals("DEN"));
            }
        });

        // Set custom renderer and editor for jTable1's checkbox column (column 7)
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setCellRenderer(new CheckboxRenderer());
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setCellEditor(new CheckboxEditor(new JCheckBox()));
    // Explicitly set default renderers for all columns
    for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        if (i != 7) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(jTable1.getDefaultRenderer(jTable1.getColumnClass(i)));
        }
    }
        // Assuming you have other components/layout code here
        // ...
        jTable1.revalidate();
        jTable1.repaint();
        pack();
        //jTable1.updateUI();
    }

 static class CheckboxRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, 
                                                   boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
                                                   int row, int column) {
        // Set colors based on selection state
        if (isSelected) {
            this.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            this.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            this.setBackground(table.getBackground());
            this.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }

        // Your existing logic to enable or disable the checkbox based on column 8's value
        if (table.getValueAt(row, 8).equals("DEN")) {
            this.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            this.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Set the checkbox's selected state based on the cell's value
        this.setSelected((Boolean) value);

        return this;
    }
}

    
    static class CheckboxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
        public CheckboxEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
            super(checkBox);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            JCheckBox checkbox = (JCheckBox) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
            if (table.getValueAt(row, 8).equals("DEN")) {
                checkbox.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                checkbox.setEnabled(true);
            }
            checkbox.setSelected((Boolean) value);
            return checkbox;
        }
    


    
    
    
}
```

I wanted this to display the populated jTable with column 7 enabled/disabled based on the string value in column 8. I used the GUI Builder in Netbeans to construct the jTable1 table initially.

Comment: Post an [mre] demonstrating your problem. Your basic approach seems correct in that you are attempting to override the "isCellEdiable" method. However, we don't have access to your database so we can't test the code. The MRE should have hard coded data in the table. One row with data so the checkbox is enabled and the other row with data so the check box is disabled. Note there is no need for a custom renderer or editor. Just override the "getColumnClass" method to return Boolean.class for the column with the check box.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1539602/131872 for a simple MRE.

Comment: There is also no need to explicitly set the cell renderers when you override the getColumnClass() method.